# Proof for equivalence relation $ f(x) \sim g(x) $ on differentiable function if $f'(x) = g'(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $ f(x) $ and $ g(x) $ is differentiable function prove that we can define an equivalence relation on functions by letting $ f(x) \sim g(x) $ if $ f'(x) = g'(x) $.

Since $ f'(x) = g'(x) $ we can conclude that $ f(x) - g(x) = c $, this result can be used to prove that the relation is transitive. However I am not able to prove that the relation is reflexive and symmetric as well.

Comment: Well if $f'(X) = g'(x)$ does $g'(x) = f'(x)$?  Does $f'(x) = f'(x)$ imply that $f'(x) = f'(x)$?

Comment: Equality implies transitivity. If $f'(x)=g'(x)$ and $g'(x)=h'(x)$ then obviously $f'(x)=h'(x)$. The same for reflexivity and symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

Reflexive is pretty straight forward, you just have to show $f $~$ f$, since $f'=f'$,
Symmetric is true, too: It is to show that, if $f$~$g$, then $g$~$f$. Since $f$~$g$, it holds that $f'=g'$, therefore also $g'=f'$.